# pythonic way to return object based on parameter type

Tags: python

I have a simple class that can operate on a variety of base classes (strings, list, file... handed to it in Python3.x and return the same type. For now, I am using `isinstance` for type checking though have read all the admonishments of doing so.

My question is what is the pythonic way of writing this function. 'Duck typing' seems more appropriate for testing that the correct type was used. I considered overloading with passing type `[func(type, input)]` or testing for `hasattr`. I want the code to be consistent with best practices, future friendly and up-gradable by a programmer other than myself.

Comment: I'm confused, is this a function that takes an object then returns another object that is the same type as the input or a class that is instantiated with some kind of thing?

Comment: How can a class operate on a 'base' class?

Comment: IMO, the "Pythonic" way of doing things would be to do no initial type checking and instead catch any exception caused by assuming the presence of an attribute or method. If one occurs, try the next possibility, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than checking the actual *type* of the object, you should check the *behavior* of the object.

What I mean by that is rather than

```
isinstance(foo, str) or isinstance(foo, list) or ...
```

You are more interested in whether it is a sequence, meaning it has defined `__iter__` for example

```
hasattr(foo, '__iter__')
```

In this sense you don't really care what the object is per se, rather you just want the objects to behave a certain way.

Similarly if you wanted the objects to be "index-able" you could check

```
hasattr(foo, '__getitem__')
```

You could follow this pattern to enforce your "duck typing" design.

Comment: It might be better to use `isinstance(foo, collections.Iterable)` or `isinstance(foo, collections.Mapping)`, although that probably requires a perfect world where types register themselves with the appropriate base classes.

Comment: @chepner not at all, any object that implements `__iter__` is tested `True` as an instance of `Iterable` and anything with `__getitem__` and `keys` is considered a `Mapping`.  Inheriting from/ registering with the abstract base class may speed up the check since it looks for taht first but otherwise testing it like that will work fine.

Comment: I'm testing that, and it doesn't appear to be true. I define a class with a `__getitem__` method, but an instance of it is not testing as being an instance of `collections.Mapping`. (That would be nice, though.)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I tried adding everything else that `Mapping` appears to promise: `keys`, `__len__`, `__iter__`, and `__contains__`, but the `isinstance` check still returns `False`. Can you confirm that this should work and my test is just missing something?

Comment: hmm thats odd I thought that had worked for me... I guess I was wrong, `Mapping` doesn't recognize correctly implemented classes.